# Problem with displaying the elements of a cell array

Tags: matlab

I have tried to create vector matrix array, to add integer elements after their arrival.

```
a={[1 1 1 1 1]; [3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3]; [4 4]; [5]};
print(a);
```

That code gives me this error:

[image: error]

Comment: Do you know what `print` does? https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/print.html You may want `disp()`?

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at the [documentation for `print`](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/print.html?searchHighlight=print&s_tid=srchtitle_print_1). It is used to:

> Print figure or save to specific file format

What you want is either [`disp`](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/disp.html) which is used to

> Display value of variable

Or [`fprintf`](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html) which is used to:

> Write data to text file (which can be the console)

Or even simpler: Just write

```
a % Note the absence of ';'
```

Upon encountering an operation without semicolon, MATLAB aromatically displays the result in the console. So this is enough to print you variable.